# Getting an error while creating external content type based on WCF service

Tags: external-content-type, wcf, business-data-catalog

I created a WCF Service in Visual Studio and wanted to create an external content type based on it but I get an error message while creating the content type:

"Error loading URL ... this normally happens when URL does not point to a valid discovery document, service description, or XSD schema"

The service I created is generated by VS and I didn't add any custom code yet.
just to test BDC.

Comment: What metadata URL are you point it at when creating the content type?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the paths are valid and accessible.
In my case the hostname could not be able to resolved, even I have written the address without hostname.

Since I was using a WCF service and deployed in some other server, the metadata link was created with hostname. 
Even you write the metadata and endpoint addresses with ip, the service might access the metadata through hostname.

Adding the hostname into hosts file, solved my problem.